# Blank page on vercel deploy [Larvel vue vite]

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vite

I deployed to vercel my laravel vue vite app, but its just a blank page

**This is the code that i have in app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    @inertiaHead

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://www.pup.edu.ph/about/images/PUPLogo.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nprogress/0.2.0/nprogress.min.css" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    @inertia

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Rx+T1VzGupg4BHQYs2gCW9It+akI2MM/mndMCy36UVfodzcJcF0GGLxZIzObiEfa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**vite.config.js file**

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css', 
                'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        manifest: true,
        outDir: 'build',
    },
    base: './',
});
```

Im really wondering what is the problem, build was successful but its just plain blank white page and sometimes its manifest error